# is it possible to override the implementation of a richfaces tag?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

for example the rich:dataScroller has the following implementation classes:

```
<component-type>org.richfaces.DataScroller</component-type>
<component-class>org.richfaces.component.UIDataScroller</component-class>
<cdk:handler-class>org.richfaces.taglib.DataScrollerHandler</cdk:handler-class>
<cdk:renderer-type>org.richfaces.DataScrollerRenderer</cdk:renderer-type>
```

would it be possible to switch these classes to some other classes? the new classes would probably extend the onces up, but would override some methods. DataScrollerHandler (super class ComponentHandler) has the following 2 methods:
-onComponentCreated 
-onComponentPopulated

so the question would be: is it possible to override these classes without defining a new custom tag? so implement the onComponentCreated and still use:

```
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
...
rich:dataScroller id="scroller" execute=....
```

Richfaces 4.2.2
jsf 2.1.7

Comment: _"is it possible to override these classes without defining a new custom tag? "_ Yes you can... Try... you already seem to know where to change things...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the component definition in your app's faces-config.xml, e.g.

```
<component>
    <component-type>org.richfaces.DataScroller</component-type>
    <component-class>com.example.myNewScroller</component-class>
</component>
```

Comment: is there a way to override the handler and the renderer class in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

the solution works for the component class. for the renderer following configuration can be used:

```
    <render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.richfaces.DataScroller</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.richfaces.DataScrollerRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.agentes.rfa.richfaces.RfaDataScrollerRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
    </render-kit>
```

i still did not find a good solution to override the handler-class. maybe something like this [Override ui:insert and ui:include-Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263233/override-uiinsert-and-uiinclude-handler)